# Swift: execute an operation conditionally on Publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I'm using Combine for networking and I want to have some of the combine operations executed only if a certain condition is present, for instance if a local boolean variable `needsDecoding` is true I want to add `.decode(type:,decoder:)`:

```
if (needsDecoding) {
   return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                .map(\.data)
                .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
} else {
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                .map(\.data)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

That code above works but is it possible to conditionally add `.decode()` to the chain?

Comment: This won’t be possible as-is, because differ in their output type. One returns `T`, while the other returns just a `Data`. What exactly were you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to have the decoder conditionally, it's a generic function.  But I guess I need a dummy type for when there is no need for a decoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for the moment that we try to write a generic function that does the same thing, accepts some data and returns either a generic parsed type or the original data:

```
func conditionallyDecodeSomeData<T>(data:Data) -> What_Goes_Here? {
    ...
}
```

Your question is pretty similar to "What type should this function return".  The answer is the type that is the most general superset of all possible results.  That's probably `Any`. (though you want it in a `Result` monad so it's probably `Result<Any, Error>`).  Using `Any` would work, but its a pretty bad 'code smell'

If you have a limited number of return types then you could create an enumerated type:

```
enum OperationResults {
    case justData(Data)
    case oneParsedResult(Result1)
    case anotherParsedResult(AnotherResult)
}
```

Then your Combine pipeline could produce `AnyPublisher<OperationResults, Error>`. But if you want something truly generic then you would probably have to use `AnyPublisher<Any, Error>` which is not satisfying.